# onStop() fragment doesnt stop mediaplayer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I tried to stop my song from playing when going from Fragmant A to Fragment B with the use of `onStop()` but i cant get it to work.

This is the debugging result:
[image]

My mediaplayer variable is getting the song properties but skipping the --> `mediaplayer.isPlaying` statement.

When im inside my Fragment B it still continue to play the song.

What am i doing wrong?

*NOTE: I dont play my music from my Fragment A (i just add the songs inside here). I play the songs from my custom adapter. Dont know if that may be the case but if so --> then i cant call `onStop()` inside my adapter.*

**EDITED:**
This is my adapter class:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

//Create variables
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
int layout;
Song currentSong;
ArrayList<Song> arrayList;
Context context;

//Constructor
public ListViewAdapter(int layout, ArrayList<Song> arrayList, Context context) {
    this.layout = layout;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
}

//ViewHolder class holding my views
private class Viewholder {
    TextView artistTxt, songNameTxt;
    ImageView playB, stopB;
    CircleImageView artistImg;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    //Create viewholder variable
    final Viewholder viewholder;

    //Check if view is null
    if (view == null) {

        //Create new ViewHolder object
        viewholder = new Viewholder();

        //Inflate my view
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_customlayout, null);

        //Find my view id's
        viewholder.artistImg = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.artistImgBackgroundDetail);
        viewholder.artistTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artistTxt);
        viewholder.songNameTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songNameTxt);
        viewholder.playB = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.playB);
        viewholder.stopB = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.stopB);

        //Set my view to viewholder
        view.setTag(viewholder);
    } else {
        viewholder = (Viewholder) view.getTag();
    }

    //Assign song to my arraylist
    final Song song = arrayList.get(position);

    //Set my views to their resources
    viewholder.artistImg.setImageResource(song.getArtistImg());
    viewholder.artistTxt.setText(song.getArtist());
    viewholder.songNameTxt.setText(song.getSongName());

    //get all songs
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, song.getSong());

    //Play button click performed
    viewholder.playB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            //Checks if my current song is null and creates a new song
            if (currentSong == null) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, song.getSong());

            }

            //if mediaplayer is not null and my current song is not equal to the new song i clicked on
            if (mediaPlayer != null && currentSong != song) {

                //resets the mediaplayer and creates a new song from the position in the list
                mediaPlayer.reset();

                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, song.getSong());
                viewholder.playB.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_black);

                mediaPlayer.start();
                viewholder.playB.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_black);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                viewholder.playB.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_black);
            }

            //check if current song is null or the newly clicked song is equal to my current song
            //if true then assign the newly clicked song as my CURRENT one
            //--so it doesnt play the same song for every single one
            if (currentSong == null || song != currentSong) {
                currentSong = song;
            }
        }
    });

    //Stop song when click performed
    viewholder.stopB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //stops my current song and make it null
            if (currentSong != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();

                currentSong = null;
                viewholder.playB.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_black);
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add a method to stop the media player in your adapter:

```
public void stop() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null
    }
}
```

And call the method when the fragment is stopping:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stop();
}
```

Comment: The thing is that the mediaplayer variable is **NULL** and therefor cannot stop the song. I somehow need to access the current song that is playing --> that current song is inside my adapter where i initialize it. But as i said in my post - i dont know how to access it (IF that is the solution).

Comment: Interesting, yet you declared it as an instance variable. You probably want find a way to assign it when you play a song so that you can keep track of it within an activity, and stop it whenever is appropriate. Maybe attaching a listener to your adapter will do the trick.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by adding a listener to my adapter?

Comment: Never mind, I see you have updated your question, thanks for sharing the adapter code. You could try adding a method to stop the media player in your adapter, so that you can conveniently call it to stop from fragment or activity. I've updated my answer too.

Comment: Thank you sir! It works now! But i have a question tho.. How can i make the song i listen to - from my listview,  continue playing inside my fragment B (where i have the details of the song)? E.g. in my Fragment B i also have a play/pause button and i like to pause the song from that detailed fragment also.

Answer (score 1):

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(...)
.
.
.
mediaPlayer.stop()
```

You create a new player and then stop it. You never stop the one that was playing already.

Comment: I thought of that too but how do i get the mediaplayer that is playing from inside my adapter?

Comment: @Delice So your media player is on your adapter and not in the fragment ? Where do you create your adapter in ? What is the adapter code ? If you can edit that code into your post we may be able to help you more.

As a comment, I wouldn't recommend having any logic/non view related things in your adapter. It should only link your view with your  dataset, nothing else.

Comment: I updated my thread and added my adapter. Sorry for the inconvenience.